# VS 2012 Intellisense cannot open source file *.tlh - Intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I am working on a big solution that contains a mix of C# and C++ code using Visual Studio 2012 Professional with the latest Resharper plugin.

I obtain a fresh copy of the entire solution from source control.

As expected, Intellisense places its curly red lines under many types and fields in C++ code before I compile my Solution for the first time. However now these squiggly lines do not disappear even after (successfully) compiling the entire solution.

I get 100+ Intellisense errors saying "Intellisense: cannot open source file .tlh

But these files definitely exist at the given location and VS has full access rights to them as I start it with elevated rights..

I am even able to jump into the namespaces, declarations or whatever with the red lines underneath so the code definitely exists.

How do I make Intellisense worke again and make these annoying lines disappear?